# Angular 6 - Create next (child/form) component on click. Copy component on click. Generate multiple child forms

Tags: angular, onclick, angular6, dynamically-generated, formbuilder

I have project that may contain many tasks and I want to show it in following way:

I have part of the form - "main project info" with some fields and below is a button which adds task to this project, or multiple tasks if you will (another form /s which is connected to parent one).

Multiple tasks it's what cracks me because my "placeholder" function which generates task form for styling purposes is just a fake one (it shows form, another and another one but it simply copy the first one, NOT GENERATE as it should, so it's impossible to save muliple tasks to the database).

**Can you help me to generate task component which will be shown after clicking button and allow me to send response to database?**
Easier/simpler = better

```
        <form [formGroup]="projectForm" id="test-form" *ngIf="arrayItems.length">
            <div class="form-group">

                <label>Title:</label>
                <input name="title" class="form-control" formControlName="title">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>State:</label>
                <select class='form-control'
                        formControlName="state">

                    <option value='active'>Active</option>
                    <option value='inactive'>Inactive</option>

                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Comment:</label>
                <input name="comment" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="comment">
            </div>

            <app-project-new-task *ngFor="let task of tasks" [arrayItems]="arrayItems" [projectForm]="projectForm.controls['projectTasks']">

            </app-project-new-task>


            // Here calling fake function to "plug" component
            <button (click)="addTask()">
                <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'plus']"></fa-icon>
            </button>

            <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Add to database</button>
        </form>
```

===================================================

```
<form [formGroup]="projectForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Task:</label>
    <input name="taskType" class="form-control" formControlName="taskType">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ arrayItems[0].name}}
    <label>Array item to select:</label>
    <select class='form-control' name="item" formControlName="select">
        <option *ngFor="let item of arrayItems" [value]="item['id']" [selected]="item['id'] == arrayItems[0]['id']">
            {{ item['name'] }}
        </option>

    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Comment:</label>
    <input name="comment" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="comment">
</div>
```

===================================================

```
export class ProjectNewComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChildren(ProjectNewTaskComponent)
children: QueryList<ProjectNewTaskComponent>;

public tasks = [];
public arrayItems= [];
projects: any = [];
projectForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private httpService: HttpService,
            private formBuilder: FormBuilder
) {
}


ngOnInit() {
    this.httpService.getData().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.arrayItems= res['response'];
            this.buildForm();
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );


}

buildForm(){
        this.projectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            title: ['', Validators.required],
            state: 'active',
            comment: '',
            projectTasks: this.formBuilder.group({
                taskType: ['', Validators.required],
                comment: '',
                select: [this.arrayItems[0].id, Validators.required]
            })
        });
    }
}
```

===================================================

FAKE FUNCTION

```
addTask() {
    this.tasks.push({ value: '' });
}
```

===================================================

Just InputForm here

```
export class ProjectNewTaskComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() arrayItems: string[];
@Input() projectForm: FormGroup;
public childForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
}
}
```

===================================================

Comment: Please identify your issue and provide a [mcve] reproducing it on stackblitz.

Comment: I can't really make it work on stackblitz :( https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhv5ib?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproject-new%2Fproject-new.component.html (I've never used it before but it must be some stupid mistake like wrong include or something if it works just like an Angular project... sorry)